# Noise after convolution of audio file with room impulse response while converting from python to MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, code-conversion

I am loading a room impulse response `h` from a mat file in both matlab and python. After this, I am loading an audio file and convolving with that `h`. In matlab, I am using the following code:

```
sound(conv(x,h(1,:)'),Fs)
```

Where `h` is a `4x2048`, 4 channels room impulse response (for 4 microphones) with 2048 samples, `x` is the audio file with 27077 samples and `Fs` is the sample rate.

On python, I am using the following code:

```
 import numpy as np
 import sounddevice as sd
 output = np.convolve(x,h[0,:])
 sd.play(output,Fs)
 sd.wait()
```

The output in python is simply noise and results with garbage where the MATLAB output sounds reasonable.

I have tested sizes of the sound and `h` after loading and the size of the convolved signal which are all the same. I do not know how to debug this.

The values, strangely, are not the same. For MATLAB, `h(1,1)` holds -0.0128 where python, `h[0,0]` holds -0.012767..(a long tail). Is that reasonable? If the numbers are different, is that why am I getting noise, though why should the numbers be different when I am loading both from the same file?

Am I using the right way to convolve this two?

Comment: Are you sure the data is loaded correctly from the .mat file?  It is a matlab file type.

Comment: The shape is the same for the RIR. other than that, I am not sure how to check this. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Print the first 20 values to screen and make sure that they are the same as those in Matlab?

Comment: @ChrisMueller see my update. I did and they are not the same, though I do not understand why.

Comment: maybe post plot of the sound signal? at least in some range, like [0,100]

Comment: @aaaaaa, thanks. Your suggestion helped. I plotted the signals after convolution and discovered a scaling difference. apparently, MATLAB normalizes the output after the convolution, while pythons `np.convolve()` does not.

Comment: never heard of matlab normalizing convolution, but glad you figured it out :-)

Comment: Well, I may be wrong but in any case, the scaling is different for both methods.